# Unique or Multiple Controllers

Tags: php, controller, code-organization

I'm doing an app in PHP with a lot of table and I would like to organise properly my code (without framework).

The question is about controllers.

I have tables for person, region, cities, countries, districts...
I don't know if I need a different controller for each Tables (ie: regionController, countriesController...) or a controller that merges some of this tables with the possibility to get different tables entries in the same controller (ie: personController will contain a getCityByPersonId method).

Hope everything is clear.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

The persistence should have no effect on you decisions in the UI layer (which the controllers are part of). Keep in mind, that "having a database" is not actually mandatory. Your application might happen to use REST API as the persistence for, or maybe it is running just on bunch of XML files.

First of all, there is something of a difference in what you are actually making. If it is an API, then your controllers would usually be separated by "resource". But if it's a website, then it is better to define them around "pages". At the end of the day, both of these just end up combining controllers more by routing concerns - what URL they are called from.

For example, take that list of tables you have there: there actually only who concepts there: person and address. Since countries/cities/districts are not really something that is subject to frequent changes.

P.S.: Don't use "Controller" suffix for your class names. We have namespaces in php for that purpose.